# how to delete an object's attribute from ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a students array like this

```
[#<Student id: 2, admission_no: "2", gender: "m", blood_group: "A">,#<Student id: 3, admission_no: "3", gender: "m", blood_group: "A">]
```

I am getting this array via named_scope .... So is there any way to select only required attributes with named scope...
I need to delete admission_no and blood_group from this and return an array only with students id and gender.. How is it possible. Iam using rails2.3

Comment: Use Student.select('id, gender').find(:all)

Comment: Please paste your named_scope here.

Comment: Why do you need to not have them?

Answer (score 1):

`named_scope_result.select('id, gender')` will give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an array of hashes containing only the required fields, starting from your array.

```
Student.select('id, gender').find(:all)
```

will do if you want to consider all the Student objects in your database.

Starting from a generic Student array: `students`, you can achieve what you want by:

```
result = Array.new
students.each |s| do
  data = { "id" => s.id, "gender" => s.gender }
  result << data
end
```

Comment: Would just `Student.select('id, gender').find(:all).map(&:attributes)` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

do this
    Student.select('id, gender').find(:all)